# Does SQLCMD parse SQL files in advance of executing them?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm using SQLCMD to upgrade a database, and noticing the following while testing. When a sproc already exists in the database SQLCMD will print a message similar to the following to the console

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server FOO, Procedure Bar, Line 2 There
>   is already an object named 'Bar' in the database.

This is despite me having the following code at the top of the .SQL file that creates Bar

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Bar'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Found Bar sproc - dropping...'
    DROP PROCEDURE Bar
    PRINT 'Dropped Bar sproc - now recreating...'
END
GO
```

So my question is - does SQLCMD pre-parse the SQL file prior to executing it (possibly to determine if it's valid SQL syntax or not) but in doing so it doesn't realise that I've already got the defensive code at the top of the file?

If that is indeed the case can I safely ignore message 2714 in this instance?

Comment: I think the error answers your question.  Apparently it does.

Comment: That is not a SQLCMD error, that's a SQL Server error. Consider the possibility that either your check or your `DROP` didn't work. For example, do you start off in the correct database?

Comment: Furthermore, rather than drop-recreate, consider create-if-not-exists (`CREATE PROCEDURE Bar AS BEGIN RETURN END`) followed by an unconditional `ALTER`. Simpler, cleaner and maintains permissions for existing procedures.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Definitely in the correct DB, as otherwise how would it know that there's one there already? I checked master and model just to be sure ;-) that an earlier iteration hadn't put them there by accident

Comment: What I meant is that `OBJECT_ID` will return `NULL` if you're not in the right DB, and it's just about conceivable your script does a `USE database` before `CREATE`. In which case checking for existence would silently fail, and creating would noisily fail.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Re the create-if-not-exists that's an interesting pattern and one i hadn't considered, I'll definitely bear that in mind for the next time I have a need to do something similar. Thanks!